# Swap two adjacent nodes in a doubly linked list

Tags: pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am learning the concept of pointer in C programming. I wrote a function as below to swap two adjacent nodes in a doubly-linked list;

```
void swapNode(DLListNode *a, DLListNode *b)
{
    DLListNode *temp = a;
    a->value = b->value;
    b->value = temp->value;
}
```

and it doesn't work, as the value of `b` passes onto `a` successfully but, the value of `a` does not pass onto `b`. Then I found if I wrote the code like this, it works. Could someone please kindly explain the difference to me? Much appreciated.

```
void swapNode(DLListNode *a, DLListNode *b)
{
    DLListNode temp = *a;
    a->value = b->value;
    b->value = temp.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version does not take a copy of the value that `a` points to. It merely creates a second reference to what `a` already references. When `a->value` gets a new value, then of course this is synonym to `temp->value` getting a new value.

In the second version, you create a *node*, which gets its properties from what `a` references. So here you *do* make a copy of a `value` property (and the `next` and `prev` properties). Now, when `a->value` gets changed, `temp` is unrelated to that change, and so `temp.value` is still what it was before that assignment to `a->value`. And that is exactly what you need to happen to make a successful swap.

It would even be possible to *only* copy the `value` property value, and not the node (which also has other properties like `prev` and `next`), since you really only need to have a copy of `value`; nothing else (I will assume here that `value` is an `int`):

```
void swapNode(DLListNode *a, DLListNode *b)
{
    int value = a->value;
    a->value = b->value;
    b->value = value;
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very well explained. Sorry for getting back to you late. I wasn't able to access my computer until just then.